# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Heroku application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I am stuck in Michael Hartl's Ruby on Ralis (3rd Edition) on Cloud 9.

I have tried to get heroku app working, but I am getting:

> Aplication Error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

As Chloe suggested I've changed 'sass-rails' version and updated 'sass-rails'

Gemfile now:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
    gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.3'
    gem 'uglifier', '2.5.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
    gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
    gem 'turbolinks', '2.3.0'
    gem 'jbuilder', '2.2.3'
    gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0', group: :doc

    group :development, :test do
      gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
      gem 'byebug', '3.4.0'
      gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
      gem 'spring', '1.1.3'
    end

    group :production do
      gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
      gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
    end
```

As thesecretmaster advised I've migrated from sqlite3 to postgesql using [the instructions given by heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

bundle install:

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (= 0.17.1) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.2
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.0
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.0
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.0
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activejob 4.2.0
Using mime-types 2.6.2
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.0
Using activemodel 4.2.0
Using arel 6.0.3
Using activerecord 4.2.0
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.3.pre1
Using columnize 0.9.0
Using debugger-linecache 1.2.0
Using slop 3.6.0
Using byebug 3.4.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using jbuilder 2.2.3
Using jquery-rails 4.0.3
Using pg 0.17.1
Using bundler 1.7.6
Using sprockets 3.4.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3
Using rails 4.2.0
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using sass 3.4.19
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using spring 1.1.3
Using turbolinks 2.3.0
Using uglifier 2.5.3
Using web-console 2.0.0.beta3
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

heroku logs now:

```
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515528+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515529+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515530+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515531+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515532+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515537+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515538+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515539+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515541+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515539+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515540+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515544+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515543+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515545+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515546+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515546+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-11-07T04:01:15.515548+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-11-07T04:01:16.156737+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-07T04:01:16.180172+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-07T09:53:24.813502+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-07T09:53:26.649609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 3154 -e production`
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640879+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640889+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640890+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640891+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640892+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640893+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640894+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640895+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640898+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640899+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640899+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640902+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640900+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640901+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640901+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640904+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640903+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640905+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640904+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640906+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-11-07T09:53:28.640908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-11-07T09:53:29.330052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-07T09:53:29.312397+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-07T15:29:39.760673+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-07T15:29:41.134773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 36601 -e production`
2015-11-07T15:29:42.344984+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)
2015-11-07T15:29:42.344999+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345000+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345000+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345001+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345003+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345003+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345004+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345005+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345006+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345006+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345007+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345007+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345009+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345009+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345010+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.345010+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-11-07T15:29:42.853092+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-07T15:29:42.835606+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-07T19:33:16.727397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io" host=shrouded-savannah-6091.herokuapp.com request_id=9c198516-5ab2-46fa-bda4-47ee664e0fe1 fwd="90.192.204.238" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-07T21:29:52.097847+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-07T21:29:53.687754+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 31558 -e production`
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589151+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589184+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589186+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589186+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589187+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589189+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589190+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589191+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589189+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589190+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589192+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589192+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589193+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589193+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589197+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589193+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589194+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-07T21:29:55.589194+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-11-07T21:29:56.163038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-07T21:29:56.172834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-07T22:21:03.270746+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io" host=shrouded-savannah-6091.herokuapp.com request_id=511497b3-bb4b-44e6-b57d-b07c88d59eff fwd="90.192.204.238" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-07T22:43:47.751918+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io" host=shrouded-savannah-6091.herokuapp.com request_id=2cf95f62-11ed-4a2e-83c0-e1db0e75dc9e fwd="90.192.204.238" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-07T23:33:40.176852+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io" host=shrouded-savannah-6091.herokuapp.com request_id=73ebcd92-8883-4feb-b8a1-1ca06eeeca59 fwd="90.192.204.238" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.42.21 update available.
```

In `heroku install` I see I have sass-rails 5.0.3, but in `heroku logs` it is still 5.0.1.

`$ heroku open`:

```
Opening shrouded-savannah-6091... xprop:  unable to open display ''
xprop:  unable to open display ''
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'https://shrouded-savannah-6091.herokuapp.com/'
done
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.42.21 update available.
```

Comment: You'll need to post the Heroku logs - we can't do anything without seeing what's going on. You can either use `heroku logs` or install [LogEntries](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logentries) and paste the errors which appear in the live feed

Comment: @ArturS. Does it work locally? Also what are the logs at the end of your question?

Comment: I have updated the question. I have updated sass-rails, those 2 logs were just the errors I've seen before 'pg' and they were still there. If working locally means being able to open it with heroku open, then no. I don't have an idea what "working locally" means when I use Cloud 9.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to <s>close one question and</s> ask another question to keep the problems separate. Your new error is

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in '<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)
```

It looks like you didn't run Bundler, because you are still using 5.0.1. It's probably an error in the Sass gem. Try to use an older version or newer version of the gem. See which versions you have installed locally.

```
gem list sass-rails
```

Try to update to the latest gem. I have 5.0.3 and the latest now is 5.0.4. Remove the version from your Gemfile and run

```
bundle update
```

Comment: I have removed the version, seved Gemfile, put `bundle update`. Now I have in heroku logs not 2 but 3 `heroku[router]` errors.

Comment: You have to update the question with the new logs. It still shows you are using 5.0.1. Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716284/uninitialized-constant-sassscript-nameerror

Comment: Thank you, logs up to date. I have changed gemfile, saved, and updated using `bundle update sass-rails`

Comment: Still says 5.0.1. For some reason it's not deploying your changes.

Comment: I have updated the question. I could have seen that for myself... In heroku install I see I have sass-rails 5.0.3, but in heroku logs I still have 5.0.1. I hope my mistake is obvious...

Comment: Try adding the output when you run `git push heroku master`. Also, might want to ask in another question.

Comment: thank you. It helped, now in `heroku logs` I have 2 errors with `heroku[slug-compiler]` and when I want to open the site I see "page you were looking for does not exist". During `heroku logs` Cloud 9 tells me I propably have the wrong Port & IP. I have to push away ruby-on-rails until I have desire to learn something and focus on Ruby. Thank you again and sorry for using your time.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is working fine locally I would run:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

from your terminal and then reload the page. If you look in the logs you should get a better understanding of what exactly the error is.

Comment: Hi, when I typed "heroku logs --tail" I have the same errors as with "heroku logs". Now after the --tail comand I cannot type any commands (the off topic adDed question). How can I make the terminal usefull again (it has happened a few times until now)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that heroku hates `sqlite3` (read: doesn't support and doesn't allow you to have the gem in your app). Here is what they have to say https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3. Instead I would migrate to postgesql. It doesn't make any difference in how your app will run, and your won't notice anything after you switch. I use [heroku postgres](https://postgres.heroku.com/) for my databases. To migrate you should just follow the instruction in the article I linked above. Good Luck!

You can also get out of terminal without closing the window by pressing `CTRL+C`

**update 1**

To solve your `sass` error you can use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716284/uninitialized-constant-sassscript-nameerror). Apparently it is an issue with sass 5.0.1, so you just need to update the gem.

**update 2**

Gems not updating in cloud nine could have something to do with the answer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28511839/4948732). I Don't know much about cloud nine, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, The link was very usefull and CTRL+C... embarassing as it gets. I still have those 2 errors and the app is still not working.

Comment: @ArturS. Did you migrate to postgres?

Comment: Yes. new heroku log is in the question - I followed the steps in your link.

Comment: @ArturS. I've updated the answer to answer your other two questions. If you found this useful please up vote!